# Integration of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Kindly guide me as to how the solution to the above question came.

Question is- $$\int (y\cos(x) + \sin(y) + y\,) dx $$

Solution is -  $y \sin(x) + x\sin(y) + xy$

Kindly guide me. I know the question is very simple but my mathematics is very poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the integral is with respect to $x$, we may regard $y$ as a constant. Thus,

$$ \int (y \cos x + \sin y + y )\mathrm{d} x = - y \sin x + x\sin y  + yx + C$$

Where $C,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Remember, if $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$$ \int \alpha f(x) \mathrm{d} x = \alpha \int f(x) \mathrm{d} x $$

Now, think of $\alpha$ as your $y$ in your specific problem.

Comment: how x is added to siny and y?. Also, in the solution given in the book, its (+)ysinx.

Comment: I editedmy asnwer

Comment: thanks but i want to know how x is added to siny and y that it became xsiny+ yx?

Answer (score 2):

$x$ is the variable and $y$ is a constant

hence $\int y\cos(x) \, dx=y\int \cos(x) \, dx (+C)$, $\int \sin(y) \, dx=\sin(y) \int 1 \, dx$, etc ...

Comment: this is a poor answer.

Comment: @fred i want to know how x is added to siny and y that it became xsiny+ yx?